# print a character from an array, and move the cursor down a row in C

Tags: c, printf

I want to print a character from a character array (a string would work too), wait a second, move the cursor down, and print the next character.

The following code moves the cursor down, but either prints invisible characters, prints off-screen, or doesn't print at all.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void delay(int seconds)
{
    int milliseconds = 1000 * seconds;

    clock_t start_time = clock();

    while (clock() < start_time + milliseconds);
}


int main() {

    char message[] = { "Testing" };
    int message_size;
    message_size = strlen(message);
    int x;
    x = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < message_size; i++) {
        printf("\x1b[%i;1%c\n", int(x), message[i]);
        delay(1);
        x++;
    }
}
```

Is there something I did wrong?

Expected output is:

```
T

*wait one second*

e

*wait one second*

s

*wait one second* 

...
```

Etc.

Comment: `int(x)` is a syntax error, or you're using a new dialect of C.  Is that a typo, or is this C++?

Comment: @WilliamPursell It's a typo, what's the right way to go about doing something like that?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include an example of exactly what you expect the output to be.

Comment: You don't need to write terminal escape characters to the screen, you can just `printf` to `stdout` and flush the `stdout` buffer every second.

Comment: @Cheatah How would I go about doing that? I'm very new to C in general, so I don't really know much about what I'm doing, I just saw someone else did it that way in an example and I didn't know any other way of doing it.

Comment: Did you also find the `delay()` function somewhere else? I would instantly fire the programmer burning CPU cycles like that.

Comment: Yeah, I found it somewhere else too.

Comment: @Hidden_R3d, whatever book had the `delay` function, it is obsolete. We don't write homemade busy-wait sleep functions to burn CPU cycles anymore. We have Bitcoin-mining for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ANSI escape sequence is wrong. To move the cursor to terminal position x,y, you have to send the sequence `"\x1b[x;yH"`. Basically you forgot to terminate the sequence with the letter `H`.

So your `printf` statement should be:

```
printf("\x1b[%i;1H%c\n", x, message[i]);
```

Note that I changed `int(x)` to `x`. (The correct way to cast/convert a value to `int` in c would be `(int)x`, but `x` is already `int`, so any cast/conversion would be silly)

In your post you don't state that you want to always starting from line `1` in the terminal when printing. If all you want to do is to move to the beginning of next line, `printf("%c\n", message[i]);` would be enough.

Other issues:

Don't do busy-waiting, it eats CPU. Besides, you implementation is wrong, `clock_t` is supposed to use microseconds. Every OS has some sort of sleep function. Use it.

If you want to print on the top of the screen. You could set the terminal position once. And do normal `printf` from there.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* For sleep function */
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {

    char message[] = "Testing";

    /* Move to top left corner */
    printf("\x1b[1;1H");
     
    for (const char *m = message; *m; m++) {
        printf("%c\n", *m);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: My implementation would be very similar, but I would omit the terminal escape sequence, because I feel it is not necessary given OP's description.

Comment: @Cheatah, Since the example in the question had terminal positioning, and the bug was caused by wrong escape codes, I left it in the answer. But I also made it clear where it is, so it can be easily removed.

Comment: Thanks for this, but could you explain how ``for (const char *m = message; *m; m++)`` works? It's a little confusing to me.

Comment: The for loop is just loops through the characters in the string directly rather than using an index. The variable `m` points to a character in the string. The expression `*m` just mean the character `m` currently points at. And `m++` makes `m` point to the next character. The loop starts with `m=message` meaning that `m` points to the first character, and ends when `*m==0`. (Strings are zero-terminated). You can naturally loop with an index `i` as you did originally. I just wanted to show a different take on it. Incrementing a pointer rather than index is sometimes less buggy.

Answer (score 0):

I made it a bit simpler for you, here we go:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libc.h>

int main() {

    char message[] = { "Testing" };

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(message); i++) {
        printf("%c\n", message[i]);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `libc.h` is non-standard. Use `#include <unistd.h>` for `sleep`-function. The value of `strlen(message)` is not supposed change. No need to recalculate it each iteration.  And finally `char message[] = "Testing";` is more "idiomatic" than `{ "Testing" }`.